# Configuration for a network lab

Tags: linux, networking

[image]

Hello all, this is the configuration I am trying to produce. Disregarding the VMNET8 I want to set up the static network for VMNET2 with the network 10.0.2.0/24.

[image]

Starting with the Linux server and VMNET2 I calculated the Inet address: 10.0.2.2, subnet masK: 255.255.255.0, Default Gateway: 10.0.2.1.

What I am confused about is; what is the default route? Is it the default gateway which then is 10.0.2.1?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default route is the destination for traffic that a specific route is not known for.

Specifically in your example:
some device inside 10.x.x.x will not know how to reach 192.x.x.x it will only be aware of 10.x.x.x - you cannot move traffic outside of this range without routing.

If a default route exists, all traffic where the destination is unknown, will be forwarded to that address in the hope of reaching a destination
So... if your linux box is the default gateway, devices inside the LAN will configure a default route to the linux box, so they can reach off-lan networks.
Specifically in your example, the linux box doesn't need the default route- it is aware of both the 10.x.x.x and 192.x.x.x networks, as it has interfaces in both.  Your devices that are completely isolated inside each LAN will require a default route to find other LAN's. 

A device completely inside 192.x.x.x would have a default route pointing to the linux box's 192.x.x.x interface, the linux box is now acting as the default gateway.
A device completely inside 10.x.x.x would have a default route pointing to the linux box's 10.x.x.x interface, the linux box is now acting as the default gatway on the other side too.

Comment: So you're saying that the default gateway would instead by 10.0.2.2? Since it should go through an interface

Comment: I updated my answer, see if you questions is answered.

Comment: Ah I get you. But just for my understanding - "Task 3: Although the default gateway is already set to the correct IP address for your topology, it is important to know and be able to use the command for setting a default gateway."

Comment: Is that a question ?  I'm not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Yeah, so i'm on the linux server it is just pinging myself?

Comment: Please consider appending your question with something specific- I'm sorry but I really can't understand your comments in context of your question.

Comment: Ok, so yes in a way the linux server is pinging itself... but that's not how they want you to approach thinking about this.  Instead they are saying your virtual machine inside the 10.x.x.x network, is pinging the linux server's interface in the 10.x.x.x - think of the virtual as a 'real machine' for the purposes of the network.

Comment: I am on the linux server, how can I test ping the linux server when I don't have a host inside the 10.0.2.0/24 network